# Why hadoop jobtracker reducer progress bar cannot get 100%, but this job has completed

Tags: hadoop

I use hadoop 0.20.0 to run a program on a cluster of 4 nodes. However, when I check the jobtracker:50030, I found that the hadoop jobtrcker displayed reducer progress bar cannot get 100%, but the jobs has completed successfully.The screen captures are as follows. I am really curious about why the situation.
[image]

However, my job has completed succcessfully.
[image]

[image]

Comment: This is interesting! Might be a bug!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the jobtracker getting the progress reports. However since Hadoop 0.20.0 was released in 2009  and there were [quite a few releases since then](http://hadoop.apache.org/releases.html) -it is kind of a moot point